# Variance of $X$ vs. $X^2$

Tags: random-variables, variance

> Let $X$ be a discrete random variable and suppose $\mathrm{Var}(X)>1$. How do $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X^2)$ compare?"

Is this enough information to solve?

I think that $\mathrm{Var}(X^2)$ is larger than $\mathrm{Var}(X)$, but I only arrived at the answer by creating a hypothetical situation and solving it, but not sure if that holds in all cases or if there was a more obvious or intuitive way to come to this conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ takes values from {$-1,1$}, then $X$ has a positive variance but $X^2=1$ has zero variance.

On the other hand for a Bernoulli variable $I$, take $Y=aI$ then
$$
\text{E}(Y) = ap
$$

$$
\text{E}(Y^2) = a^2p
$$

$$
\text{E}(Y^4) = a^4p
$$

So 
$$
\text{Var}(Y) = a^2pq
$$
$$
\text{Var}(Y^2) = a^4 pq
$$
So depending on $a$ we will get any relation.